# Sqlite Browser Tutorial

Tags: android, database

Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial for sqlite browser. I cant seem to find what am looking for hope you guys can help thank you.

Comment: Your question is very vague: Are you looking for a tutorial about using a SQLite browser? Writing a SQLite browser? Being a SQLite browser?

Comment: SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1.

Comment: try it http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: Try this detailed tutorial [link](http://androidgifts.com/import-sqlite-database-into-android-using-sqlite-browser/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Android SQLite Manager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/) if you're looking for a browser program for your SQLite Db

Comment: Really? It worked for me, here's the full link- http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/ you may need to give it a few minutes to load if you're on a sketchy connection (like mine)

Comment: just found a link and it worked for me so thanks anyway. i do like the look of this.

Answer (score 2):

[MOTODEV Studio](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/download/) has a SQLite GUI browser that works with the emulator and rooted phones. You can install as a full package or as plugins into your existing Eclipse environment.

[image: MOTODEV Studio GUI SQLite Browser]

Disclaimer: I'm the product manager. Free to use, requires registration to download.